# Get ALL results from database with username

Tags: php, html, mysql

How can I keep checking for posts with PHP? I have a piece of code that goes through and gets all the posts. When I do `echo  $row['post_message'];` I get all of the messages. When I set it as a variable like this `$post =  $row['post_message'];`, and do `<h2><?php echo $post;?></h2>` I only get one result. Here's my code

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT post_message FROM posts WHERE post_user = :username");
$stmt->bindValue(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$row = $stmt->fetchAll();


$stmt->execute();
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $post =  $row['post_message'];
}
```

So when I do `echo`  I get `I like pie I like pie 2alex likes food`, and when I store it in a variable I get `alex likes food`. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you `$stmt->execute();` twice?

Comment: Copy and paste error. Fixed @Darren

Comment: possible duplicate of [php function not returning all results from a MySQL query in a foreach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517652/php-function-not-returning-all-results-from-a-mysql-query-in-a-foreach)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue lies in your `while` loop. You keep overwriting the `$post` variable. It should be:

```
$posts = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $posts[] =  $row['post_message'];
}
```

Which should return:

```
Array (
    [0] => I like pie I like pie 2,
    [1] => alex likes food
)
```

---

This allows you to do something like this (*as an example*):

```
foreach($posts as $post) {
    echo 'The user posted: ' . $post . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: When echoing `posts` all I get is `Array`

Comment: @user302975 it is an array and you'd have you use `print_r($posts)` to see the values.

Comment: Then I get [this](http://i.imgur.com/oLPPahG.png) but I want to format the result like [this](http://i.imgur.com/1APPuoj.png). Like post titles

Comment: @user302975 I've shown you how to get the results, now its up to you to display it as you like. As you can see I've supplied the `foreach` that you'd use. Now print it as you wish....

Comment: You seem to be missing a `'` right before the end of the line break. @Darren

Comment: Actually, that should read as `echo "The user posted: " . $post . "<br />";` - but that's just me ;-)

Comment: It'd be even harder using Maxwell Smart's "shoe phone" ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Challenge accepted! ;-P Maybe I should get [this](http://www.joetech.com/images_for_posts/uglycell_3.jpg) one haha.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Only the best to achieve Those goals ;-)